# I need help finding what is wrong with my code. This is from Larry Ullman's Book PHP for the Web

Tags: php

I am studying this book from Larry Ullman, PHP for The Web, and I am stuck on Chapter 12 script 5. The first scripts worked just fine. Can anyone spot my error? My operating system is ubuntu 14.04 and I am using LAMP with PHP 5.5.9.

```
<?php // Script 12.5 - add_entry.php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    // Connect and select:
    $dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '*******');
    mysql_select_db('myblog', $dbc);


    // Validate the form data
    $problem = FALSE;
    if (!empty($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['entry'])) {
        $title = trim(strip_tags(S_POST['title']));
        $entry = trim(strip_tags($_POST['entry']));
    } else {
        print '<p style="color: red;">Please submit both a title and an entry.</p>';
        $problem = TRUE;
    }

    if (!$problem) {

        // Define the query:
        $query = "INSERT INTO entries (entry_id, title, entry, date_entered) VALUES (0, '$title', '$entry', NOW())";


        if (@mysql_query($query, $dbc)) {
            print '<p>The blog entry has been added!<p>';
        } else {
            print '<p style="color: red;">Could not add the entry because:<br />' . mysql_error($dbc) . '.</p><p>The query being run was:' . $query . '</p>';
        }

    } // No Problem!

    mysql_close($dbc); // Close the connection

} // End of form submission IF

?>`
```

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting when you try to use your script? Be sure to turn on [`display_errors`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) when debugging your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

```
$title = trim(strip_tags(S_POST['title'])); // note S instead of $
```

Change that to:

```
$title = trim(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
```